# Data size definition in C programming while using mathematical expressions

Tags: c

When using mathematical operators in c programming, it is very important to use casts or define size of variable properly. I need help in it.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t    a;
    uint8_t     b;
    uint8_t     d;
    uint64_t    c;
    float       cd;

    a = 4294967295;
    b = 2;
    d = 2;
    c = a * b * d;
    cd = c;

    printf("%f\n", cd);

    return 0;
}
```

The result variable is large enough to store the `2 * 2 * uint32_max`. However I noticed that the `b` or `d` variable need to be 64 bit wide (or use cast) to get the proper result. For this time I thought the mathematical operations takes place in the result variable, but it looks like is not true. Can somebody explain me which variable need to be widened (b or d) and what is the theoretical background behind it?

What is the situation in division? Should I consider whether I want to divide a 32 bit number with a 8bit long. will the result be in that case 8 bit only? Does any rule about the type of the denominator?

Comment: you should read about ``implicit arithmetic conversions``.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions

Comment: No variable needs to be widened. You can type `c = (uint64_t)a * b * c;` as well.

Comment: @user1810087 It's not "widening" of a variable (in a sense OP uses this term). It just creates a temporary from a casted value of a variable, which remains untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, the evaluation of an expression is determined by the operator and its operands, not by where the result will eventually be stored.

The expression `a * b * d` is structured as `(a * b) * d`. So `a * b` is evaluated, and then the result is multiplied by `d`.

One of the rules for `*` is in C 2018 6.5.5 3:

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

The *usual arithmetic conversions* are defined in 6.3.1.8 1. They are a bit complicated, and I give most of the details below. Applying them to your example:

- In `a * b`, `a` is a `uint32_t` , and `b` is a `uint8_t`.
- The *integer promotions* convert `b` to an `int`—essentially all arithmetic in `C` is done in a width of at least `int`.
- If `int` is 32 bits or narrower, `a` remains `uint32_t`. Otherwise, `a` is converted to `int`.
- If converted types of `a` and `b` are both `int`, the conversions are done, and the multiplication is performed.
- If the converted type of `a` is `uint32_t`, `b` is converted to `uint32_t`, and the multiplication is performed.
- Then the multiplication with `d` is performed the same way.

So, if `int` is 32 bits or narrower, the multiplications are performed with `uint32_t`, and the result is `uint32_t`. If `int` is wider, the multiplications are performed with `int`, and the result is `int`.

Casting either operand to `uint64_t` would cause the arithmetic to be done with `uint64_t`. (Except it is theoretically possible that `int` is wider than `uint64_t`, in which case the arithmetic would be done with `int`, but that is still satisfactory—performing a cast guarantees the arithmetic will be done with at least that width.)

For real numbers, the usual arithmetic conversions are largely:

- If either operand is `long double`, the other is converted to `long double`.
- Otherwise, if either is `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
- Otherwise, if either is `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
- Otherwise, the *integer promotions* are performed on both operands.
- Then, if both have the same type, no further conversion is performed.
- Otherwise, if both are signed or both are unsigned, the narrower (actually “lesser rank”) operand is converted to the type of the other.
- Otherwise, if the unsigned operand is the same width or wider (greater or equal rank), the signed operand is converted to the type of the unsigned operand.
- Otherwise, if the type of the signed operand can represent all the values of the type of the unsigned operand, the unsigned operand is converted to the type of the signed operand.
- Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned type that has the same width as the signed operand.

The integer promotions are defined in 6.3.1.1 2. They apply to all integer types as wide as or narrower than `int` or `unsigned int` (technically of rank less than or equal to the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`), including bit-fields of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

Comment: Best answer I've seen all week.

Comment: That is a great amount of information, and it took me time to understand, but really appreciate the help. Originally my aim was to save space in an 8 bit microprocessor environment, therefore I tried to use as narrow variables as can store the value of it. In the future I will take the above tips into account.

Answer (score 3):

When you perform the multiplication `a * b * d`, what will happen is that `b` and `d` will get *promoted* to `uint32_t` (or `int` if `int` is wider than `uint32_t`) to match the type of `a`. However, this operation might overflow. So what you need to do is to cast at least one of them to `uint_64_t` to prevent this from happening.

Do note that `(uint64_t)(a * b * d)` will NOT work. Type casts has lower priority than parenthesis.

Comment: More strictly the type might be `int` if `int` is wider than `uint32_t`.

Comment: @eerorika: But an expression consisting of an `int` and a `uint32_t` might be a `uint32_t`.

Comment: @Bathsheba oh yea. I was assuming two `uint8_t` which is not the case here.

Comment: @eerorika: Indeed, it's subtle - one reason why I waded in with an answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba Are you sure it will get promoted to a *signed* int?

Comment: @Broman: Yup, the type of `unsigned char * unsigned char` is an `int`, for example.

Comment: `b` is not promoted to `uint32_t`. The *integer promotions* would make it `int` at most. After the integer promotions, the *usual arithmetic conversions* convert it to the type of `a`, if `a` is wider than `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`a * b * d` is an expression of type `uint32_t`, or `int` if `int` is wider than `uint32_t` (due to the conversion rule for `uint8_t`).

The fact that this expression is assigned to a wider type is not a factor. *That's* the crux of the issue.

Writing `c = 1ULL * a * b * d` is a tractable fix.

Comment: Actually, I think the *crux* of the issue is the OP’s belief or hypothesis that the evaluation is affected by the target of the assignment. Stating that expression evaluation is determined by the operands and is not affected by the target of an eventual assignment would put them on the right track.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That's what I meant to say but presumably it doesn't come over clearly enough.